# How to make Excel say "3 apple in Box1" or "2 orange in Box2" based on two lists?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Based on the lists here:

Fruits and Boxes

[image]

| Fruits | Boxes |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | Box1 |
| Orange | Box2 |
| Apple | Box1 |
| Pear | Box2 |
| Cherry | Box1 |
| Apple | Box1 |
| Orange | Box2 |
| Pineapple | Box4 |
| Pineapple | Box4 |
| Banana | Box5 |
| Apple | Box2 |
| Pear | Box1 |
| Grape | Box6 |
| Apple | Box3 |
| Grape | Box6 |

How to make Excel say something like "3 apple in Box1" or "2 orange in Box2"?

I would like to make exact list below:

- 3 Apple in Box1
- 1 Apple in Box2
- 1 Apple in Box3
- 1 Banana in Box5
- 1 Cherry in Box1
- 2 Grape in Box6
- 2 Orange in Box2
- 1 Pear in Box1
- 1 Pear in Box2
- 2 Pineapple in Box4

I have tried COUNTIF and Pivot. Pivot gave me good result but it was not refreshing when I change the values. And I couldn't make the template "3 Apple in Box1".

If it's possible, could you please help me with that?

Answer (score 4):

Alternative:

```
=LET(
    ζ,A2:A16&" in "&B2:B16,
    UNIQUE(SORTBY(MMULT(N(ζ=TOROW(ζ)),SEQUENCE(ROWS(ζ),,,0))&" "&ζ,ζ))
)
```

Comment: Nice use of TOROW versus TRANSPOSE. Is there a performance difference between the two, or is it mainly for keeping the formula shorter and therefore easier to read?

Comment: Simply the latter!

Comment: Very clean version by the way. Better approach then mine, I'd say.

Answer (score 2):

If your range would be in `A2:B16` you could use this:

```
=LET(a,     SORT(A2:B16,{1,2}),
     u,     UNIQUE(a),
     aa,    INDEX(a,,1)&"|"&INDEX(a,,2),
     uu,    INDEX(u,,1)&"|"&INDEX(u,,2),
     mm,    MMULT(--(TRANSPOSE(aa)=uu),SEQUENCE(ROWS(aa),,1,0)),
     join,  HSTACK(mm,INDEX(u,,1),EXPAND("in",ROWS(mm),,"in"),INDEX(u,,2)),
BYROW(join,LAMBDA(j,TEXTJOIN(" ",1,j))))
```

[image]

Comment: You appear to have '*1 Pear in Box1*' and '*1 Pear in Box2*' in the wrong order.

Answer (score 1):

### Join Counts

**Ordered**

```
=LET(dl,A2:A16,dr,B2:B16,del," ",der," in ",
    d,dl&der&dr,ds,SORT(d),
    u,UNIQUE(ds),m,XMATCH(u,ds),
DROP(SORT(HSTACK(XMATCH(u,d),
    VSTACK(DROP(m,1),ROWS(d)+1)-m&del&u)),,1))
```

**Sorted**

```
=LET(dl,A2:A16,dr,B2:B16,del," ",der," in ",
    ds,SORT(dl&der&dr),
    u,UNIQUE(ds),
    m,XMATCH(u,ds),
VSTACK(DROP(m,1),ROWS(ds)+1)-m&del&u)
```

[image]